# Tuckey use-query-setting exclusion

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using Tuckey rewrite filter to make some rules to map urls. For example, I got the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
         <rule enabled="true">
            <note>Do not process URLs targeting fonts</note>
            <from>/*fonts*</from>
            <to last="true">-</to>
         </rule>

        <rule enabled="true">
            <note>Do not process calls to images</note>
            <from>/*images</from>
            <to last="true">-</to>
         </rule>

        <rule enabled="true">
            <note>Process the rest of the links </note>
            <from>/(.*)$</from>
           <to type="passthrough">/</to>
        </rule>
     </urlrewrite>
```

What the rules above allow me to do, is to passthrough anything with /fonts and /images and everything else (catchall), gets redirected back to the homepage.

I would like a rule to not process any query parameters and let it passthrough as is. I tried various regex strings, including

```
     <rule enabled="true">
        <note>Do not process calls to /?*</note>
        <from>^/(.*)?</from>
        <to last="true">-</to>
      <rule>
```

but they did not work.

Essentially any URL, such as https://example.com/promo/def get rewritten back to / (which is working).

What is not working is that https://example.com/promo/?def gets rewritten back to / and not being passed through. That's not working right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly tell tuckey filter that you want your query string to be appended to the target URI. 
It is possible by using `qsappend` attribute in your `<to>` property.

```
<rule enabled="true">
        <note>Do not process calls to /?*</note>
        <from>^/(.*)?</from>
        <to qsappend="true" last="true">/</to>
<rule>
```

If you use version below 4.0, there is an alternative solution with appending `query-string` to the target URI explicitly.

```
<rule enabled="true">
            <note>Do not process calls to /?*</note>
            <from>^/(.*)?</from>
            <to last="true">/?%{query-string}</to>
<rule>
```